# C++:Linker command with exit code -1 in xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I was implementing a suffix array in xcode using c++ when I got the following error:

```
ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (100000121018926 max is +/-4GB): from _main (0x100001310) to _L (0x5AF417B0F130) in '_main' from /Users/priya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cfquestions-boqlvazrozappdeetfhesfsohczs/Build/Intermediates/cfquestions.build/Debug/cfquestions.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My code for the suffix array is as follows:

```
char a[size1];
int ans[size2][size2];
struct node{
    int gg[2],pos;
}L[size1];
int step=1,ct=1;
bool comp(node a, node b){
    return a.gg[0]==b.gg[0]?(a.gg[1]<b.gg[1]?1:0):(a.gg[0]<b.gg[0]?1:0);
}
int main(){
    int TT;
    cin>>TT;
    while(TT--){
        set<int> s;
        //a.clear();
        int n=strlen(a);
        scanf("%s",a);
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)ans[0][i]=a[i]-'a';
        for(;ct<strlen(a);step++,ct<<=1){
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                L[i].gg[0]=ans[step-1][i];
                L[i].gg[1]=i+ct<n?ans[step-1][i+ct]:-1;
                L[i].pos=i;
            }
            sort(L,L+n,comp);
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                ans[step][L[i].pos]=i>0&&L[i].gg[0]==L[i-1].gg[0]&&L[i].gg[1]==L[i-1].gg[1]?ans[step][L[i-1].pos]:i;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(s.find(ans[step-1][i])!=s.end()){

            }
            else s.insert(ans[step-1][i]);
        }
        cout<<s.size()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: The code runs fine on any other code. I tried even much more complex codes; but it works fine. Hence there must be something wrong with this piece of code- but I am not able to figure out what!

Any help would be appreciated thanks!!

Comment: Values of size1 and size2?

Comment: #define size1 1000001
#define size2 100001 decreasing size2 worked..But why didnt xcode show Bad memory acess and linker error?

Comment: Per the numbers you put up in your comment, that array of arrays of char is over 93GB. I dunno what the problem is being solved, but that seems a pretty brutal way to try and solve it, and it won't stand a chance of fitting in a 32bit address space. Compile as 64bit and you *may* stand a chance, but even there unless the host is sporting a boatload of RAM the thrashing will be a heavy price to pay.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** The reason is the size of `ans`, as pointed out in the comment by @WhozCraig after you added the sizes.  My guess regarding why the linker error message names `_L` is that the compiler put `main` at a lower address and then the global data in order, giving the too big RIP offset to `L`.

---

In one of the for loops you have `i = 0` and access `L[i-1]`, which is a very large number for the array index .

**edit:** but that should give a runtime failure or error  and not give a linker error.